# Union of two linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

Hi i have two linq statements:

```
from d in dtDummy.AsEnumerable() 
where d["Role_id"].ToString() == "0" 
select d;`

from d in dtDummy.AsEnumerable() 
join t in dtTest.AsEnumerable() on d.Field<int>("role_id") 
equals t.Field<int>("role_id") 
where (d["role_dept"].ToString() !=  t["role_dept"].ToString() || d["role_dept"].ToString() != t["role_dept"].ToString() || d["role_desc"].ToString() != t["role_desc"].ToString() || d["role_all_clients"].ToString() != t["role_all_clients"].ToString() || d["role_admin"].ToString() != t["role_admin"].ToString() || d["role_super_admin"].ToString() != t["role_super_admin"].ToString()) 
select d;
```

How to write a linq single statement to get the same result as i would get if i do union on both the statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can use `Union`:

```
var union = (from d in dtDummy...).Union
            (from d in dtDummy...);
```

Personally I'd separate the two out for clarity though:

```
var query1 = ...;
var query2 = ...;
var union = query1.Union(query2);
```

I'd also use `Field<string>` rather than calling `ToString`... or probably project these into a cleaner object model which would allow your queries to be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
(from d in dtDummy.AsEnumerable() where d["Role_id"].ToString() == "0" select d).union

(from d in dtDummy.AsEnumerable() join t in dtTest.AsEnumerable() on d.Field<int>("role_id") equals t.Field<int>("role_id") where (d["role_dept"].ToString() != t["role_dept"].ToString() || d["role_dept"].ToString() != t["role_dept"].ToString() || d["role_desc"].ToString() != t["role_desc"].ToString() || d["role_all_clients"].ToString() != t["role_all_clients"].ToString() || d["role_admin"].ToString() != t["role_admin"].ToString() || d["role_super_admin"].ToString() != t["role_super_admin"].ToString()) select d)
```